# Triggering pip requirements.txt from catkin build

Tags: ros, catkin, pip

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to get catkin build to run pip install -r requirements.txt?

Some of the python package dependencies for my package are in version control systems, and because of this I think I need to use pip to install them instead of putting them in setup.py.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221471/triggering-pip-requirements.txt-from-catkin-build/) by [CatherineH](https://answers.ros.org/users/22373/catherineh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 248 on 2015-11-24

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Conceptually this is not quite right. `rosdep` is the tool which should be used to install dependencies. You can add rosdep rules which resolve to pip installations (including directly from version control). You can have these rules locally or propose them for the rosdep database (https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/tree/master/rosdep).

You should run `rosdep` once to satisfy dependencies and then the build (`catkin_make`, `catkin_make_isolated`, or `catkin build`) should be called many times and therefore it shouldn't do any dependency resolution as part of the build.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2015-11-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As William's answer states, rosdep is the way to go.

For example, I can replicate the call to pip by first creating a rosdep.yaml file in my directory with the contents:

```
pip-seaborn:
 ubuntu:
  pip:
    packages: [seaborn]
pip-vikit-py:
 ubuntu:
  pip:
    packages: [vikit-py]
    alt_install_cmd: git+git://github.com/CatherineH/rpg_vikit.git#egg=vikit_py&subdirectory=vikit_py
```

Then, I modify my package.xml file to include:

```
<run_depend>pip-seaborn</run_depend>
<run_depend>pip-vikit-py</run_depend>
```

Then, I created the file  /etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d/40-my-list.list, which contains the line:

```
yaml file:///my-package-path/rosdep.yaml
```

Finally, I run:

```
rosdep update
rosdep install --from-path my-package-path
```

---

Originally posted by [CatherineH](https://answers.ros.org/users/22373/catherineh/) with karma: 248 on 2015-11-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2